# Android Studio - Trying to display battery temperature in status bar as notification

Tags: android, battery, temperature

I am using Android Studio and trying to display the battery temperature in the Status Bar as a notification. I have successfully accomplished this task, but there is one issue. The temperature shows up as 0.0 Celsius... Here is my code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements     

OnClickListener
{
Button start, clear;

Notification noti;
NotificationManager nmgr;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    getInit();

    nmgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti = new Notification(R.drawable.flame, "Battery Temperature", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    float temp = ((float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0)) / 10;


    noti.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Battery Temperature", String.valueOf(temp)  + " C", pIntent);
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

}
public void getInit()
{
    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(this);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
}



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId())
            {

        case R.id.btn:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Info")
                    .setMessage("Battery Info © 2015 Natan Rosenfeld")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Intent startcredits = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startcredits);
            break;
                case R.id.btn3:
                nmgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,noti);
                break;
                case R.id.btn4:
                nmgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);


    }

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your device has a temperature sensor?

Comment: yes, i can display the temperature in a textView but not in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the OnClickListener() method. The onClickListener() method gets you to onClick(), so I don't see how in your code you're ever reaching onClick() because you never call it. I'm new to android, but from the app that I'm writing I've been using and what seems to be the standard when you create a button:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```